# Override default HashAlgorithm.Create()

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, sha256, signing

I've been trying to override the default value from `SHA1` to `SHA256` of what `System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.Create()` returns. Based off the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.create?view=netframework-4.8), it is supposed to be override-able.

I came across this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/map-algorithm-names-to-cryptography-classes), but it seems to only mention mapping a custom hash algorithm to override one of the existing ones. I want to just override the default of `SHA1` to a default of `SHA256`.

Is that possible using the article above?

Something like this?

```
<configuration>  
   <mscorlib>  
      <cryptographySettings>  
         <cryptoNameMapping>    
            <nameEntry name="System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm"  
                       class="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256"/>  
         </cryptoNameMapping>  
      </cryptographySettings>  
   </mscorlib>  
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, it's possible.

If you need to apply new default hash algorithm in every running .NET Framework application on machine just write this section inside `machine.config` file:

```xml
<mscorlib>  
    <cryptographySettings>  
        <cryptoNameMapping>  
            <cryptoClasses>  
                <cryptoClass DefaultHashAlgorithm="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>  
            </cryptoClasses>
            <nameEntry name="System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm"  
                    class="DefaultHashAlgorithm"/>  
        </cryptoNameMapping>  
    </cryptographySettings>  
</mscorlib>
```

Note that `machine.config` file placed here:

**x32**:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]\config\machine.config
```

**x64**:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[version]\config\machine.config
```

Also you can change default algorithm on every built-in hash algorithm by change `DefaultHashAlgorithm` attribute. See list of algorithms [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptoconfig#remarks).

Answer (score 2):

The drawback of changing `machine.config` is that it affects all applications that will use `System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm`.

Another approach is to use [`CryptoConfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptoconfig?view=netframework-4.8) class. The next code snippet registers `SHA256Managed` as a default hash algorithm:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

...

CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(
    typeof(SHA256Managed),
    "System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm");
```

This changes default hash algorithm only for current application.

**Note** that a concrete implementation `SHA256Managed` of an abstract class `SHA256` must be used.

Comment: Since I don't have the source for the other application, it was better for me to change the config of the box. Although I would much rather do this approach.