# Change Executable Hash Algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, hash, cryptography, sha256

We have an application build in .NET Framework 4.8, and for security issue we need to change the Hash Algorithm from SHA-1 to SHA-256.

We find this hash algorithm trough ILSPY( as you can see on the image).

I have also downloaded Ilspy source code and I find that the hash algorithm was retrieved from the code AssemblyDefinition.HashAlgorithm.

[image]

For solve this issue I tried to:

- Sign ClickOneManifest
- Sign .exe with certificate
- Obfuscate the code

Without success :(

How we can change hash Algorithm of a dll?

I tried, to sign the dll with certificate, obfuscate with dotfuscator, sign the manifest.
and  also try this [Override default HashAlgorithm.Create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60962252/override-default-hashalgorithm-create)
but seems don't work.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. What kind of security issue do you have that depend on the assembly hash algorithm? Or is it just the kind of "never use SHA-1 anywhere" security mandates that ignores the context of how it is used?

Comment: Yes, it's only a error raised from our global security team. There is not any security issue on the assembly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify it using [`AssemblyAlgorithmIdAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyalgorithmidattribute) like this:

```cs
[assembly:AssemblyAlgorithmId(System.Configuration.Assemblies.AssemblyHashAlgorithm.SHA256)]
```

(Note that the value is a `System.Configuration.Assemblies.AssemblyHashAlgorithm`, not a `System.Reflection.AssemblyHashAlgorithm`, annoyingly.)